# Building an istringstream with a string temporary

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

While trying my code to answer another question I found out that the following didn't compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// (main omitted)
const char * coin = "3D";
istringstream ss(string(s));
int i;
ss >> hex >> i;              <--- error here
cout << (char) i << endl;
```

It failed with the following error:

```
test.cpp:15:11: error: invalid operands of types ‘std::istringstream(std::string) {aka std::basic_istringstream<char>(std::basic_string<char>)}’ and ‘std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)’ to binary ‘operator>>’
```

While the following compiled and ran properly :

```
const char* coin = "3D";
string s(coin);
istringstream ss(s); // or directly istringstream ss("3D")
int i;
ss >> hex >> i;              
cout << (char) i << endl;
```

If I look at the definition of the constructor of `istringstream`, it accepts `const std::string&` (actually the `basic_string<char>` equivalent), and that compiles. So I guess the template argument deduction has a behaviour I don't understand and create a not so conform `istringstream`, but why ?

I am using GCC 4.6.1 (Ubuntu flavor).

EDIT : since istringstream is a typedef, I doubt there's any problem with templates in the end.

Comment: Try changing it into: istringstream ss((string(s)));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
istringstream ss(string(s));
```

Your compiler thinks that's a declaration of a function taking a `string` (named `s`) and returning an `istringstream`. Surround the argument in parentheses in order to disambiguate it.  By the way, what is `s`? Did you mean `coin` there?

```
istringstream ss( (string(coin)) );
```

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) if you are confused.

In this particular case, you could of course have just done this:

```
istringstream ss(coin);
```

If your compiler supports it, you can also avoid the MVP using uniform initialization syntax:

```
istringstream ss{string{coin}};
```

That probably looks a bit odd to most people, I know it looks odd to me, but that's just because I'm so used to the old syntax.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was hit by the most vexing parse. It hurts the first time ;). I now understand better why the type in the error message looked strange.

Comment: `Your compiler thinks that's a declaration of a function taking a string (named s) and returning an istringstream` And it's right

Comment: He could have equally well said `istringstream ss(coin);`.